# chainselect ruby on rails No me funciona

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Intento hacer un select con un formulario, pero cuando voy a guardar me sale esto, y no sé qué tengo mal.

> undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass
>
> around line #17
>   `<%= select_tag "pais", options_from_collection_for_select(@paises, "id", "name" ), class: "form-control", :include_blank => "Seleccione Pais" %>`
>
> [image: <%= select_tag "pais", options_from_collection_for_select(@paises, "id", "name" ), class: "form-control", :include_blank => "Seleccione Pais" %>]

**Formulario**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@persona) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :identificacion %>

    <%= f.input :nombre %>
    <%= f.input :email %>

  </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
       <label>Pais</label>
    <%= select_tag "pais", options_from_collection_for_select(@paises, "id", "name" ), class: "form-control", :include_blank => "Seleccione Pais" %>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>Departamento</label>
       <%= select_tag "departamento", "<option value="">Seleccione departamento</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
       <label>Municipio</label>
       <%= select_tag "municipio", "<option value="">Seleccione Municipio</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){

   // Empieza codigo para select anidados
   $("#pais").change(function(event, data) {

    var id_pais = $('select#pais :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/personas/select_departamento',
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: 'GET',
    data: { idpais: id_pais },
    success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#departamento');
        $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione Departamento</option>');
        $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
        var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.name);
        $select.append($option);
        });      
    }
    });
    // inicializar los selects
    var $select = $('#municipio');
    $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione Municipio</option>');
  });

  $("#departamento").change(function(event, data) {
    var id_departamento =  $('select#departamento :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/personas/select_municipio',
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: 'GET',
    data: { iddepartamento: id_departamento },
    success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#municipio');
        $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione Municipio</option>');
        $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
        var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.name);
        $select.append($option);
        });      
    }
    });

  });

  // Termina codigo para select anidados  

});
```

---

**En las routes `routes.rb`**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :municipios
  resources :departamentos
  resources :paises
  get 'static_pages/home'

  get 'static_pages/help'

  root :to => 'personas#index'
  resources :personas do
    get :select_departamento, on: :collection
    get :select_municipio, on: :collection
  end

end
```

---

**En el `Controller`**

```
class PersonasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_persona, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /personas
  # GET /personas.json
  def index
    @personas = Persona.all
    @paises   = Pais.all
  end

 # select anidados
  def select_departamento
    rs = Departamento.where(:pais_id => params[:idpais]).order('name').all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
    end
  end

  def select_municipio
    rs = Municipio.where(:departamento_id => params[:iddepartamento]).order('name').all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
    end
  end

  # GET /personas/1
  # GET /personas/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /personas/new
  def new
    @persona = Persona.new
    @paises   = Pais.all
  end

  # GET /personas/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /personas
  # POST /personas.json
  def create
    @persona = Persona.new(persona_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @persona.save
        format.html { redirect_to @persona, notice: 'Persona was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @persona }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @persona.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /personas/1
  # PATCH/PUT /personas/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @persona.update(persona_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @persona, notice: 'Persona was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @persona }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @persona.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /personas/1
  # DELETE /personas/1.json
  def destroy
    @persona.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to personas_url, notice: 'Persona was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_persona
      @persona = Persona.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def persona_params
      params.require(:persona).permit(:identificacion, :nombre, :email, :municipio_id)
    end
end
```

---

**En la base de datos**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170221123516) do

  create_table "departamentos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "pais_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["pais_id"], name: "index_departamentos_on_pais_id"
  end

  create_table "municipios", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "departamento_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.index ["departamento_id"], name: "index_municipios_on_departamento_id"
  end

  create_table "paises", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "personas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "identificacion"
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "municipio_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.index ["municipio_id"], name: "index_personas_on_municipio_id"
  end

end
```

---

Los  select funcionan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modelo

```
class Persona < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :municipio
end
```

Este fue error  que salió después de agregar `save!`

> Validation failed: Municipio must exist

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que al guardar `@persona` en tu acción `create` alguna validación falla y, por ende, no se guarda; y de acuerdo a la lógica establecida en esa acción, se debe mostrar tu vista `new` (`render :new`):

```
if @persona.save
  format.html { redirect_to @persona, notice: 'Persona was successfully created.' }
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @persona }
else
  format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @persona.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

Pero en tu accion `create` **no** existe la variable`@paises`, la cual es necesaria para generar el `select` dentro de  `new.html.erb`, en:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@paises, "id", "name" )
```

El error se genera ya que `@paises` es nulo o `nil` (el *helper* `options_from_collection_for_select` llama al método `map`).

Para solucionarlo simplemente agrega `@paises` tal como lo haces en tu acción `new`:

```
if @persona.save
  format.html { redirect_to @persona, notice: 'Persona was successfully created.' }
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @persona }
else
  @paises = Pais.all
  format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @persona.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

---

Con respecto al segundo error, pareciera que estás proporcionando un valor inválido para `municipio_id`; sin embargo te recomiendo utilizar `save!` en lugar de `save` **temporalmente** para identificar el error más rápido.

Considerando lo anterior, así quedaría tu acción `create`:

```
def create
  @persona = Persona.new(persona_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @persona.save!   # << Aquí está el cambio
      format.html { redirect_to @persona, notice: 'Persona was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @persona }
    else
      @paises = Pais.all
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @persona.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Al utilizar `save!`<sup>1</sup> se mostrará otra pantalla de error con la descripción de la validación que falló e impidió que se guardara el registro exitosamente.

<sup>1</sup> *Es muy importante que **regreses tu código a `save`** una vez que identifiques el error, de lo contrario tendrás una pantalla de error cada vez que un usuario meta un dato equivocado.*

---

El error (posterior a incorporar `save!`) es muy claro:

> Validation failed: Municipio must exist

En la forma estás enviando un `id` de `Municipio` que no existe; por lo tanto debes asegurarte que

1. tu tabla de `municipios` tenga información y
2. el municipio que selecciones en tu forma exista en la tabla `municipios`.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por responder pero lo  hice  y no me dio, se bloquea  gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ ¿A qué te refieres con "se bloquea"?, ¿te muestra algun error?

Comment: puse la imagen para  que la vieras. gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Checa la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: como  crees   que es el erro, y en que parte esta  yo apenas estoy  comenzado y me apasiona y  estoy haciendo lo posible para mejorar y entender,  muchas gracias por la ayudad.

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ El error lo dice todo, necesitas proporcionar el `id` (a través de tu forma) de un `Municipio` que exista. Ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: hola,  pero  en la en la tabla municipio  si existen  datos guardados,  uno como organiza para que  municipio_id reciba el id de municipio,  yo creo  es donde esta el problema. gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Lo mejor sería que generes otra pregunta con la información relevante (vista y javascript) y marques esta respuesta como aceptada (click en la paloma verde), pues esta pregunta se ha desviado ya de su problema original. Esta es la forma en que funciona SO: un problema por pregunta. :)