# chainselect ruby on rails, problema con el javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Intento hacer un select con un formulario.

**Formulario**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@persona) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

    <%= f.input :identificacion %>

    <%= f.input :nombre %>
    <%= f.input :email %>

  </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
       <label>Pais</label>
    <%= select_tag "pais", options_from_collection_for_select(@paises, "id", "name" ), class: "form-control", :include_blank => "Seleccione Pais" %>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>Departamento</label>
       <%= select_tag "departamento", "<option value="">Seleccione departamento</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <%= select_tag "persona[municipio_id]", "<option value="">Seleccione Municipio</option>".html_safe,
   class: "form-control" %>

</div>
<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){

   // Empieza codigo para select anidados
   $("#pais").change(function(event, data) {

    var id_pais = $('select#pais :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/personas/select_departamento',
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: 'GET',
    data: { idpais: id_pais },
    success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#departamento');
        $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione Departamento</option>');
        $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
        var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.name);
        $select.append($option);
        });      
    }
    });
    // inicializar los selects
    var $select = $('#persona_municipio_id');
    $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione Municipio</option>');
  });

  $("#departamento").change(function(event, data) {
    var id_departamento =  $('select#departamento :selected').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: '/personas/select_municipio',
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: 'GET',
    data: { iddepartamento: id_departamento },
    success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#persona_municipio_id');
        $select.empty().append('<option value="">Seleccione Municipio</option>');
        $(data).each(function (index, o) {    
        var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.id).text(o.name);
        $select.append($option);
        });      
    }
    });

  });

  // Termina codigo para select anidados  

});
```

---

**En el `Controller`**

```
class PersonasController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_persona, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /personas
  # GET /personas.json
  def index
    @personas = Persona.all
    @paises   = Pais.all
  end

 # select anidados
  def select_departamento
    rs = Departamento.where(:pais_id => params[:idpais]).order('name').all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
    end
  end

  def select_municipio
    rs = Municipio.where(:departamento_id => params[:iddepartamento]).order('name').all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render json: rs }
    format.html
    end
  end

  # GET /personas/1
  # GET /personas/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /personas/new
  def new
    @persona = Persona.new
    @paises   = Pais.all
  end

  # GET /personas/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /personas
  # POST /personas.json
  def create
    @persona = Persona.new(persona_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @persona.save
        format.html { redirect_to @persona, notice: 'Persona was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @persona }
      else
          @paises   = Pais.all
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @persona.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /personas/1
  # PATCH/PUT /personas/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @persona.update(persona_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @persona, notice: 'Persona was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @persona }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @persona.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /personas/1
  # DELETE /personas/1.json
  def destroy
    @persona.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to personas_url, notice: 'Persona was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_persona
      @persona = Persona.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def persona_params
      params.require(:persona).permit(:identificacion, :nombre, :email, :municipio_id)
    end
end
```

---

Los  select funcionan.

Modelo

```
class Persona < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :municipio
end
```

Este fue error  que salió después de agregar `save!`

> Validation failed: Municipio must exist

La tabla municipio  existen datos guardados, uno como organiza para que municipio_id reciba el id de municipio, yo creo es donde esta el problema.

yo apenas estoy comenzado y me apasiona y estoy haciendo lo posible para mejorar y entender, muchas gracias por la ayudad.

ya  me guarda  pero  cuando va ir a cargar el show

** me saca un error**
en la vista muestra

**log**

[image: imagen1]
[image: imagen2]

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para describir únicamente el problema actual; el primer error ya fue resuelto [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75875/chainselect-ruby-on-rails-no-me-funciona) por lo que no es necesario repetir todo; puedes incluir un link como referencia y contexto.

Comment: @AlterLagos Realmente solo la primera parte es duplicada, la cual debería ser editada (creo) pues la segunda parte si es una pregunta distinta a la original. ¿Qué se debería hacer en estos casos?

Comment: Gerry, solo debes incluir una pregunta en cada publicación. Por lo tanto, lo recomendable es que lo que llamas "segunda parte" se mueva a una nueva pregunta para que pueda ser atendida como corresponde. Sigue esta guía: __[mcve]__.

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Veo que ya agregaste los logs (bien), ahora falta eliminar la primer pregunta. No es necesario dejar ni las rutas ni la información de la BD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en dos partes:

1. Cómo estás pasando los parámetros para crear una `Persona`, es decir, como estás estructurando tu forma.
2. El nombre que estás asignando a municipio es `municipio` en lugar de `municipio_id`.

Para corregirlo actualiza el `select_tag` de municipio de tal forma que se llame `municipio_id` y sea incluido en el grupo `personas` que se envía en los parámetros:

```html
<%= select_tag "persona[municipio_id]", "<option value="">Seleccione Municipio</option>".html_safe, class: "form-control" %>
```

Dado que esto cambiará el `id` de tu `select`, también debes actualizar tu script, cambiando las dos líneas que tienen:

```js
var $select = $('#municipio');
```

por:

```js
var $select = $('#persona_municipio_id');
```

Comment: De toda  manera se  bloquea como anteriormente.

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ ¿Puedes mostrar el log completo del error? Por favor incluye la línea donde se muestran los parámetros. Agrégalo en la pregunta, y aprovecha para eliminar la duda ya resuelta, de lo contrario probablemente se cierre esta pregunta (como duplicada).

Comment: hola ya la organize

Comment: mire  arriba ya lo edite  con estos ejemplos

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Viendo los parámetros enviados, noto dos cosas: 1) parece que únicamente cambiaste el nombre a `municipio_id` en lugar de `persona_municipio_id` y 2) El `select_tag` no parece estar renombrado a `"persona[municipio_id]"`. ¿Podrías verificar que los cambios estén hechos?

Comment: ya  lo organiza  como tu  dijiste y  en el controlador  esta @paises   = Pais.all  gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ bien, aún falta quitar el primer problema (el repetido); pero bueno, ¿ya hiciste los cambios?, ¿se resolvió el error con ellos?

Comment: no se  ha resuelto.  gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ ¿qué error obtienes? ¿Podrías actualizar tu código en la pregunta con los ajustes que hiciste?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76652/chainselect-ruby-on-rails-problema-con-el-javascript#comment141162_76685con el código  de arriba la pantalla

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ En tu último log se ve ahora otro error, estás enviando en `municipio_id` la descripción, en lugar del id; dice `municipio_id: envigado`.

Comment: Ya  la actualice MIRE  como tengo el codigo. gracias

Comment: Desconozco si el valor `envigado` sea correcto, sin embargo no es un `id`. ¿Qué valores obtienes al consultar `select_municipio`? Podrías obtenerlos por medio de cURL. O bien, pon `puts rs,inspect` temporalmente al final de tu acción para que el resultado se imprima en pantalla. Muestra que resultado es.

Comment: hola  el valor envigado  es  un  id  de municipio  que  lo trae  select.  yo estoy  haciendo estos select  es para parametrizar  los municipios  ò 
 hay otra formas mas fácil de hacerlo.  gracias

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Ese valor no está como `id` en `Municipio`; debes formar el `select` de tal forma que los valores sean los `id` de `Municipio`.

Comment: jum no me esta trayendo los selec

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Ese parece ser otro error, ¿has cambiado algo o por qué antes si los traía?

Comment: ya  guarda  pero  muestra  otro error  ya en log gracias @Gerry

Comment: @MIGUELANGELGILRODRIGUEZ Por favor genera una pregunta nueva con el nuevo error, al modificar la pregunta actual invalidas la respuesta. Lo correcto sería marcar esta respuesta como aceptada (dando click en la paloma verde), dado que resolvió efectivamente el problema y abrir una nueva con el error y el código que lo genera (es decir, tu archivo `show.html.erb`. Así es como funciona Stack Overflow.